# How to pass data from WebAssembly OpenGL application to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I want to create a simple dialog in a browser that takes button click as input using WebAssembly.

I have succeeded creating an application using OpenGL, SDL2, and imGui and ported it to JavaScript using Emscripten.
But I have problems passing data from the WebAssembly OpenGL application to JavaScript.

How can I pass data from C++ to Javascript to acknowledge the web page that users have done some actions (ex: Clicking "OK" button)?

I've tried to stop the Emscripten run loop using `emscripten_cancel_main_loop`. And the application just freezes on the web page.
I'm trying to emit events from C++ to JavaScript but couldn't figure out how it works.

Comment: can't you declare JS functions and call them?

Answer (score 2):

After several attempts, I've come to an approach to dispatch CustomEvent from WebAssembly to my Web page.

The function that was used to send data looks like this:

```js
EM_JS(void, sendData, (int data), {
    window.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent("fromWASM", {
            detail: {
                data: data
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Then call `sendData()` directly on C++ code as if it was a normal C++ function.

Finally, we'll need to listen to the event on the JavaScript side with `addEventListener`:

```js
window.addEventListener('fromWASM', (event) => {
    console.log(event.detail);
});
```

I'm also wondering can we pass messages from the web page to the OpenGL application?

Answer (score 2):

You are going about this the entirely wrong way.   I simply do this in C++ to easily control my web content:

```
#include <../emsdk/emscripten/master/system/include/emscripten.h>


/* in your C++ code somewhere */
emscripten_run_script('alert(\"The operation is completed!\");');
```

emscripten_run_script will execute arbitrary Javascript code in the context of the document where the webassembly is loaded.

---

**EDIT**

If you wanted to perform the operation in reverse (calling a C++ method from the javascript context), you would want to expose the C++ method to Javascript  like this:

```
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

int myFunction(int x) {
    // Your C++ code here
    return x * 2; // Example operation
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
    emscripten::function("myFunction", &myFunction);
}
```

Now in the Javascript context:

```
// Call the C++ function from JavaScript
const result = Module.myFunction(10);

// Decide what to do with the result
console.log(result); // Use the result in your JavaScript code
```

You can even pass Javascript functions as callbacks using emscripten::val and use them like any other javascript callback.

```
#include <emscripten.h>

void myFunctionWithCallback(int x, emscripten::val callback) {
    int result = x * 2; // Example operation
    // Convert the result to a val before passing to callback
    callback(emscripten::val(result)); }

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
    emscripten::function("myFunctionWithCallback", &myFunctionWithCallback); }
```

Comment: I want to wrap the C++ function in a JS function so that it can decide what to do after the user has taken action. How can I pass the result data to the Javascript calling function using emscripten_run_script?

Comment: You would have to setup a C++ binding.